# Finding other internal domains on a network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, domain, nmap

So on my school's network, I noticed that certain school services have their own internal domain names,
e.g Blackboard can be accessed by typing "blackboard/" in a browser, Email via "stumail/", papercut via "papercut/", etc.

I actually don't remember how I found these out, but I was wondering is there a way to find other custom internal domains on the network? I thought I could use `nmap` for it but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use Multicast DNS (mDNS). For that you have multiple tools available on Ubuntu.
In any case, you need a running avahi daemon on your machine. A minimal installation requires you to install the `avahi-daemon` package and to start that, e.g. `systemctl start avahi-daemon`.

To discover hosts you can then run `avahi-browse -a` which is provided by the `avahi-utils` package on Ubuntu. The GUI alternative to this is to run `avahi-discover` provided by the package with the same name.

Alternatively to setting up the daemon and fetching `avahi-browse` you can install and run `mdns-scan`.

Comment: Please describe how to use these tools to do what the question asks. … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: Thank you @jvda and @Scott! Apparently lots of software I had installed used this as a dependency so it wasn't hard to get. I found the -r (resolve) argument very useful for my needs, i.e finding what each domain linked to.